# splitting date into year month day SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ssis, etl

Is there a way to split dates into int value year, month, and day and then insert them into SQL server DB using SSIS ?

Comment: Yes, but why? Why not store the dates in a date column?

Comment: Instead of splitting input dates it's better to create a Calendar table with eg 20 years of dates with all the extra columns you need for aggregating, reporting, filtering, eg quarter, month, week number, reporting periods. This makes filtering eg by quarter a lot faster. Reporting also becomes a lot easier, especially for reports like month-over-month comparisons that would require very complex and slow queries.

Comment: Of course you can. But you should do this if it really solve something. Always ask yourself what I am solving and what is the best solution.

Comment: I know that conditional split in sssis has this function date part and I want to know how to use it

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions, YEAR(), MONTH(), DAY()

Ex:

```
DECLARE @date datetime2 = '2022-03-09';
SELECT 
    DAY(@date) AS DAY,
    MONTH(@date) AS MONTH,
    YEAR(@date) AS YEAR;
```

| DAY | MONTH | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 3 | 2022 |

Reference :

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/year-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/month-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/day-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You can use [derived column transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derived-column-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15) with the built-in date and time functions as follows:

```
DAY([date_column])
MONTH([date_column])
YEAR([date_column])
```

Also, you can use the `DATEPART()` function as follows:

```
DATEPART( "day", [date_column] )
```